# How the limit number of enumeration in EnumSet come from?

Tags: java, enums, enumset

I found that a limit number of enumeration (**64**) is used in EnumSet. Please see a method  in EnumSet source code below (This code is captured from JDK 1.7).

```
/**
 * Creates an empty enum set with the specified element type.
 *
 * @param elementType the class object of the element type for this enum
 *     set
 * @throws NullPointerException if <tt>elementType</tt> is null
 */
public static <E extends Enum<E>> EnumSet<E> noneOf(Class<E> elementType) {
    Enum[] universe = getUniverse(elementType);
    if (universe == null)
        throw new ClassCastException(elementType + " not an enum");

    if (universe.length <= 64)
        return new RegularEnumSet<>(elementType, universe);
    else
        return new JumboEnumSet<>(elementType, universe);
}
```

From the above code we can see: if the length of Enum array is less than 64, **RegularEnumSet** is used. Otherwise, **JumboEnumSet** is used instead.

Here my questions are as follows:

1. How does this limit number of enumeration (64) comes from or how to calculate it as 64?
2. Why **RegularEnumSet** and **JumboEnumSet** are both used, What good is there in doing that?

Comment: 1. You can see in RegularEnumSet, it uses a 64-bit long instead of array. 2. JumboEnumSet is slower/bigger as it uses an array, however it can handle any size of enum you can have.

Comment: Thanks for your informaiton, Peter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not limited to 64.  There is a just a different implementation chosen if there are more than 64 items.  I haven't looked at the source, but I would guess that a `RegularEnumSet` is implemented as a bit mask using a single `long`.

Answer (score 1):

Its not, its limited to the different types available in the enum :

> [All of the elements in an enum set must come from a single enum type
>   that is specified, explicitly or implicitly, when the set is created.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)